# Best Practice for N-Tier Domain/ View Models with Skinny Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel, n-tier-architecture, ef-database-first

We are looking to move logic from our overweight Controllers into a fuller Domain, to produce skinny Controllers.

We have a question about how to build Domain Models that can provide the right information to Controllers so that View Models can be populated.

Our Database First Solution has the following tiers:

•   UI (Currently Web Project using MVC)

•   Domain

•   Repository

•   Data Access Layer – Entity Framework

•   Data (Database Project pointing at SQL Server)

Let’s say we have a variety of Views that need View Models with different amounts of data for a particular Entity e.g.

•   **OrderBasic** View Model - just an ID, Title and Date

•   **OrderWithCustomer** View Model - the above plus the Customer’s Name and Phone Number from the Customer Entity

•   **OrderWithLines** View Model - OrderBasic plus a list of the Order Lines with their information

•   etc

Our options seem to be:

1. **Create Domain Models which are similar to these.**  This does not seem right, both because the Domain Models are being influenced by the requirements of individual Views and also we are duplicating code.
2. **Create one Domain Model for each Entity with all the information that may be required.** This seems bad for performance as for some Views, more information is being populated and transported to the client than is needed.
3. **As 2 but have separate or parameterised Domain Methods that only populate required fields.** This may be more performant, but means Models are sometimes incomplete.

Is there a better way?  What is best practice?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Domain models are graphs of interconnected object that communicate with eachother and carry out your business needs and encapsulate business rules. There are also `Domain Services` that encapsulate business workflows and/or computations/algorithms.

When you model these domain objects you should not care about for anything else other than your business and it's rules. Should not care about DB or how your view looks like.

*You are also missing from your architecture the `Application Layer` where you encapsulate the use cases of the application (You can think of it that if you change your app you also change your use cases).*

App Layer sits between the UI (which includes MVC controllers) and the Domain layer and **orchestrates** entities and/or domain services to realize some use case.

From the App layer you return some DTO object (not the entity from the DB itself!) and you convert the information in that DTO to a View Model object which is very UI friendly (transform it in such a way that you could just do a simple direct data binding in the HTML).

I implemented the same architecture (maybe with small adjustments) in multiple projects and I had good results, including skinny controller that had nothing more that model state validation, 1 call into the App layer and some glue code between DTOs and view models.

There is a lot to talk about here and the approach may differ based on your own environment and non-functional requirements so always keep a birds-eye view on what are you are actually doing and if it makes sense to your particular situation.

P.S. You can find some good guidelines here (remember the dependency rule): http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Comment: This is always a good starting point.
http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/07/17/how-we-do-mvc-4-years-later/